# Containers communications in aws ecs

Tags: containers, amazon-ecs

I have a task definition that contains 4 containers and they need to communicate with each other.

[image: containers]

I already tried to use the name of the container (passer by environment variable) to try to get them to communicate, but it didn't work. With that in mind I don't think using the repository name (ECR) will work. What can I do to get the containers to communicate?

OBS: I’m using the aws web interface

Comment: What network mode are you using? Can you share the task definition?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I'm using Fargate, so the network mode is awsvpc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All containers in a `task definition` can talk to each others via `localhost` because they share the same network space. So if container1 exposes a service on port `1234` you can call it with `localhost:1234` from any other container.

Comment: So I need to have a separated service for each container ?

Comment: You don't "have to" but a task is defined as an atomic unit that shares credentials, scaling attributes, etc. For example if your containers need to scale independently they need to be in different tasks. If they need different credentials, they need to be in different tasks. If they need to be secured from each others, they need to be in different tasks. Etc.

Comment: I can't quite tell but from the name of your containers yeah it feels like they'd need to be different services. If you are starting from scratch with ECS you may want to have a look at either [Copilot](https://aws.github.io/copilot-cli/) or the [Docker Compose integration](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/deploy-applications-on-amazon-ecs-using-docker-compose/).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create a specific task definition for each docker image then create ecs service based on each task definition you have been created in the previous step, and to manage the communications between ecs services you have many option like loadbalancer, cloud map, or ecs service discovery with I prefer in term of cost and scalability. the following blog maybe helpful.[blog link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-ecs-service-discovery/)